# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous while using for loop for some values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, valueerror

Here is a row of my data frame.

```
Country Region  Happiness Rank  Happiness Score Standard Error  Economy (GDP per Capita)    Family  Health (Life Expectancy)    Freedom Trust (Government Corruption)   Generosity  Dystopia Residual
5   Finland Western Europe  6   7.406   0.0314  1.29025 1.31826 0.88911 0.64169 0.41372 0.23351 2.61955
```

The data frame consists of this kind of row for each country.
I wanted to take GDP per capita values for some countries, and I tried to use for loop to do this.
Here is the for loop:

```
country_names = ['United States','United Kingdom','Switzerland','Canada','Hong Kong','Japan','South Korea','Singapore','Australia','Germany','France','Ireland','Tunisia','Turkey','Italy']
countries_gdppercapitas= []
for countries in country_names:
    if happiness_scores[happiness_scores['Country'] == countries]:
         countries_gdppercapitas.append(happiness_scores[happiness_scores['Country'] == countries]['Economy (GDP per Capita)'].item())
```

However, this code raised an error.
`The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`
Can someone please help? I don't know how to fix this. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line

```
if happiness_scores[happiness_scores['Country'] == countries]:
```

`happiness_scores[happiness_scores['Country'] == countries]` is one expression, it is a dataframe object. It doesn't evaluate to a boolean thus you get the error `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`

Please provide more information on the condition you want on the happiness score for additional help

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` you could do something like

```
happy_threshold = 3

# select all rows that satisfy the happiness threshold condition
happy_df = df[df['Happiness Score'] > happy_threshold]

country_names = ['United States','United Kingdom','Switzerland','Canada','Hong Kong','Japan','South Korea','Singapore','Australia','Germany','France','Ireland','Tunisia','Turkey','Italy']
# select countries in your list
select_happy_df = happy_df[happy_df["Country"] in country_names]

# then you can extract the gdp_per_capita to a list format
# select the series with df["column"] then transform the pandas.Series to a list with series.tolist()
countries_gdppercapitas = select_happy_df["Economy (GDP per Capita)"].tolist()
```